# Undefined behavior warning on self-assignment comma operator operand in fold expression

Tags: c++17, undefined-behavior, assignment-operator, sequence-points, comma-operator

I'm getting a warning from GCC 10.1 about possible undefined behavior. Clang 10 does not warn.

```
warning: operation on 'init' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]

    |     (x = ... = (init = fold_op(init, elements), 0));
    |                   ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is the snippet causing the warning:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename BinaryOp, typename... Pack>
constexpr auto reverse_reduce(T init, BinaryOp&& fold_op, Pack&&... elements) -> T
{
    auto x = 0;
    (x = ... = (init = fold_op(init, elements), 0));
    return init;
}
```

It's using an `operator=` and fold expression hack to perform a reverse 'iteration' over the parameter pack.

**Is GCC right to warn here? or is it well defined behavior?**

Here is as minimal as I can make it while still reproducing the error:

```cpp
auto x = 0;
auto i = 0;
((x = (i = i, 0)) = (i = i, 0))
```

Everything I've read about sequence points, order of evaluation, and operator precedence/associativity leads me to think that this is well defined, but there are so many rules and I'm no expert.

One thing that makes me believe the warning is correct is that when I assign the result to a `constexpr` variable in clang, the result is different than in non-`constexpr` evaluation.

Comment: In evaluating an expression like `((*p1=1),(*p2=2))+((*p3=3),(*p4=4))`, the write to `*p1` would be sequenced before the write to `*p2`, and the write to `*p3` before the write to `*p4`, but operations on p1 and p2 would, individually, be unsequenced relative to those on p3 and p4,

Comment: I'm not sufficiently sure about the rules in C++ to know for certain that your code wouldn't be defined, but it seems like the same principles would apply.  In any case, if gcc or clang reports that something is undefined, they shouldn't be relied upon to process it correctly regardless of whether they're right or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambda to get rid of the warning.

Example:

```
template <typename T, typename BinaryOp, typename... Pack>
constexpr auto reverse_reduce(T init, BinaryOp&& fold_op, Pack&&... elements) -> T {
    auto x = 0;
    auto inner = [&](const auto& v) {init = fold_op(init, v); };
    (x = ... = (inner(elements), 0));
    return init;
}
```